# How to navigate deep in React Navigation with back button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation for my react native project and I want a screen which need not be in the navigation options. Lets say I have an events list page in the menu and each event in the list page will open a details page which cant be in the menu, Now I want a back button which will take me to list page again and how can I do the navigation. Currently I am guessing navigation.navigate needs the screen to be in the navigator right?

Comment: Are you trying to be able to click a push notification go to the events page and then have the other page loaded behind it so you can hit the back button?

Comment: Not a push notification exactly, My DrawerNavigator has a screen: ListEventsScreen, so when I am on the ListEventsScreen, I want to be able to go to DetailsScreen of an event and come back to ListEventsScreen. right now DetailsScreen is not registered in the navigator as it is specific to an event.

Comment: @TallPaul Do you know how to accomplish this with a push notification (as is my case)? If so can you post an answer?